# Protect apps from decompiling

Tags: java, android, 7zip, mobile-application, apktool

Is there any way to not let the app open in 7zip/ any other file archiver and also I would like to restrict the app from decompiling using apktool.

To summarize:
1. Code which does not let you decompile the apk

2.code which does not let your apk open in file archiver.

Thanks for any response.

Comment: You can't prevent people from decompiling your app. What you can do is make the output from the decompiler more difficult to understand by applying various forms of obfuscation. However, questions asking people to recommend specific tools are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: if you can't open an apk in the file archiver, it would need some android tools to open it client side

Comment: Basically I want to protect my /assets/ directory. Looks like there is no proper way.

Comment: Any computer program is a detailed, step-by-step procedure that tells the computer how to do something.  How are you going to give Joe Blo's computer such detailed instructions without making the instructions available to Joe Blo himself?  Ultimately, the only way it's possible is if you (or your agent) and Joe Blo's computer both share some secret (e.g., an encryption key) that Joe Blo himself is not allowed to know.  Q: If your computer knows things that you are not allowed to know,... If it obeys commands that you are not allowed to see, can you really call it _your_ computer?